# Javascript time between 08:30 - 20:00

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a message show between certain time ranges in a day but i cant make it work it either shows the first IF or doesnt show anything at all with an error i cant seem to figure out. what am i doing wrong?

```
var today = new Date();
var hour = today.getHours();
var minute = today.getMinutes();

if(today.getDay() == 4){
        if(hour > 8 && minute > 30 || hour < 20){
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ('come today till 20:00');
        } else if (hour > 20 && hour < 0){
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ('Come tomorrow till 20:00');
        } else (hour > 0 && hour < 8).document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ('Come today from 08:00 till 20:00');
    }
```

figured it out thanks for the help guys :)
this is how it works now.

```
        if(today.getDay() == 4){
        if((hour === 8 && minute > 30 || hour > 8) && hour < 20){
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ('Kom vandaag langs in onze showtuin tot 20:00 uur donderdag');
        } else if (hour >= 20 && hour < 24){
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ('Kom morgen langs in onze showtuin tot 20:00 uur');
        } else{
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ('Kom vandaag langs in onze showtuin van 08:00 tot 20:00 donderdag');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Think of a number that’s bigger than 20 but less than 0.

Comment: why the minutes of 8:30?

Comment: that is when the store opens if it was from 8 to 8 it would have been alot easier.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify the conditions a bit, with checking from small values to greater values, like

```
if (today.getDay() == 4) {
    if (hour < 8) {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'Come today from 08:00 till 20:00';
    } else if (hour < 20) {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'Come today till 20:00';
    } else if (hour < 24) {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'Come tomorrow till 20:00';
    }
}
```

Comment: The `hour > 8 && minute > 30` means it will work 9:31 - 9:59 + 10:31 - 10:59, etc. You need `(hour = 8 && minute >= 30 || hour > 8) ...`.

Comment: right now i made it like this `if((hour = 8 && minute >= 30 || hour >8) && hour < 20)` and its showing the right message but if i check it and change the number 8 o 9 it will just show an eror again.

Comment: @RikRook replace `hour = 8` with `hour === 8`

Answer (score 0):

Each `if` can use the previous condition to its advantage which means if you correctly sort the conditions you can make it really simple:

```
if (hour >= 20) {
    //20:00 - 23:59
}
else if (hour > 8) {
    //9:00 - 19:59
}
else if (hour == 8 && minute >= 30) {
    //8:30 - 8:59
}
else {
    //0:00 - 8:29
}
```

Comment: `=` is not an equals operator

Comment: @barbsan sorry, typo